# Why is this method not sorting the XML parser?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I would like to sort my list by Clinic name, the parser works fortunately. However the sorting technique I have used does not. Have I implemented it incorrectly?

```
    public class BookScreen extends Activity {

        //array
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        // All static variables
        static final String URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42241589/test.xml";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_CLINIC = "clinic"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
        static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
        static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
        //static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
        ListView list;
        LazyAdapter adapter;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.book_main);
            new DownloadXML().execute();
        }

        private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookScreen.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("List is loading");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
                try {
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CLINIC); //define parent node
                    // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                        map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
                        map.put(KEY_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TIME));
                        map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ADDRESS));
                        //map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        songsList.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
                Collections.sort(songsList, comparator);
                adapter = new LazyAdapter(BookScreen.this, songsList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                //Close dialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> comparator = new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
                    return map1.get(KEY_CLINIC).compareTo(map2.get(KEY_CLINIC));
                }


    };
}
```

The logcat points to an NullPointerException at `return   map1.get(KEY_CLINIC).compareTo(map2.get(KEY_CLINIC));' in the **method comparator**.

```
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885): Process: com.example.clinicbooker, PID: 885
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$1.compare(BookScreen.java:102)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$1.compare(BookScreen.java:1)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2023)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1883)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(BookScreen.java:91)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.clinicbooker.BookScreen$DownloadXML.onPostExecute(BookScreen.java:1)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-01 11:25:34.730: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator is trying to pull an entry with the key KEY_CLINIC, but there was never an entry "put" into the map with that key.

Comment: This is a renaming/Software Engineering mistake. I'm sorry. I meant to sort data by KEY_TITLE. My apologies

Comment: Did you update the code to sort based on KEY_TITLE and the exception go away?

Comment: Yes I have. The way I've named these variables could be quite misleading